# how to import the excel tabs and give the name of tabs in new column accordingly in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvl24.png) I have file named `Example.xls` in which i have data in tab `sales` and `purchase`. 
 We have data in  both tab from Column A to E. 
 When i import these data through pandas module, i want that result like Column A to F where column F should display the name sheet name. How to display the name of sheet name in pandas module?

I am using code

`all= pd.read_excel(Example.xlsx',sheet_name=['Sales','Purchas'])`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M91Ds.png)
and then

```
df= pd.concat(All[frame]for fram in All.keys())
```

and then after i want to put  the name of tabs in my data frame "All" in  the last column which is  F  respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way.

```
import pandas as pd

path = r'path_of_your_file'
workbook = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = None)
df= pd.DataFrame()
for sheet_name, sheet in workbook.items():
    sheet['sheet'] = sheet_name
    df = df.append(sheet)

# Reset your index or you'll have duplicates
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: i have error >>> import pandas as pd
>>> path = r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\kk\'
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> path = r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\kk\Example.xlsx'
>>> workbook = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = None)
>>> df= pd.DataFrame()
>>> for sheet_name, sheet in workbook.items():
 sheet['sheet'] = sheet_name
  df = df.append(sheet)
  
SyntaxError: unexpected indent
>>>

Comment: This line is your problem: path = r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\kk\'.
the last backslash escapes the closing apostrophe. You don't need that line at all anyway, the path should include the file name.

Comment: Rahul--- It is consolidating all the sheet . but what i  want to do is i want to Sheet name also in the last column so that i can read what data belongs which sheet... i y hope u get my issue now .. pls help me...

Comment: @ManojKumar I think you added the comment to the wrong answer but my code here will add the sheet name to the last column as you require.

Comment: hi Rahul -- @Reimar. how are you doing buddy . hope everything will be fine . i have raised one query hope you can help me. really appricates for your support. please check my today questions .

Answer (score 2):

The below code will solve your problem:

```
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

f_mask = r'path\*.xlsx' ## The folder path where your Example.xlsx is stored

df = \
pd.concat([df.assign(file=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0],
                     sheet=sheet)
           for f in glob(f_mask)
           for sheet, df in pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None).items()],
          ignore_index=True)
```

The code works in following way:

1. Check the base folder and take all the .xlsx files in it
2. Read the files one by one
3. Make two additional columns, one for file name other for sheet name

This solution will work if you want to do the exercise for more than 1 .xlsx file

Comment: Thank you ed 4 mins ago

Rahul Agarwal .. i will try .. but what is the role of glob ?

Comment: `Glob` is basically going to that folder and seeing different .xlsx files. In future if you want to do same exercise for multiple excel files, this will take care of it.

Comment: do i need to define all the name of tabs? i am using code all= pd.read_excel(Example.xlsx',sheet_name=['Saales','Purchas'])  and then df= pd.concat(All[frame]for fram in All.keys()).. and then after i want to put  the name of tabs in my data frame "All" in  the last column which is  F  respectivel

Comment: For above code to work properly, put all your excel files or 1 in any folder. Give that folder path in `f_mask` and simply run the code. No need to define anything. The code will take care of everything!!

Comment: i tried but showing error " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 2, in <module>
    pd.concat([df.assign(file=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0],
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined"

Comment: Updated the answer with one more package

Comment: wow is Awesome,  never thought this will with all excel file . @Rahul Agarwal .. but i am not getting the name of tab name in last column . that was my query .. could u  pls help.

Comment: I was getting when i ran the same code...it will be in the column named `sheet`. So,  what is the extension of your excel files, if it is `.xls` change the `f_mask` to `f_mask `= r'path\*.xls'`

Comment: we its imported all the data but what did not display the tab name which is sales  and purchase  in last column .. could u pls help

Comment: in your resultant df is the column name `Sheet` is getting formed or not ?

Comment: No i cant see  that name as sheet ...  :( please check above question .. i have attached the print screen

Comment: Can you also post like what you have modified in my code!! or you are using it exactly like I posted!! Bcoz same code is working on my system

Comment: I am using same code as you mentioned .. there is no change in code . Only i

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your `Example.xls` here

Comment: Rahul pls ...help me

Comment: tell me what you put in `f_mask ` in your solution

Comment: this is what i did 
>>> import os
>>> from glob import glob
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> f_mask = r'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\kk\*.xlsx' ## The folder path where your Example.xlsx is stored
>>> df = \
   pd.concat([df.assign(file=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0],
    sheet=sheet)
           for f in glob(f_mask)
           for sheet, df in pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None).items()],
          ignore_index=True)

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "__main__", line 6
FutureWarning: Sorting because non-concatenation axis is not aligned. A future version
of pandas will change to not sort by default.

To accept the future behavior, pass 'sort=False'.

To retain the current behavior and silence the warning, pass 'sort=True'.

Comment: You can ignore warning...2nd: Make a new folder in desktop lets say `Test`, Put your xl file in this `Test` folder and now your `f_mask` should be `C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Test\*.xlsx`

Comment: @ Rahul : How are you doing . i have an another query as i have stucked . Could you please help me . its realted with groupby

Comment: you can post the link of the question!! I will see and let you know!!

Comment: I am sad now .. i have asked the same question again again beacuse i did not  get the appropariate answer .. i really dont know how this app works .. Eeveryone is degarding me ..but dont see why i am asking again and again  
   ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62628305/no-one-is-able-to-help-for-groupby-by-one-level-and-give-the-rest-dublicate-data.... please help me if you can

Comment: The above link is not working!! let me know how can I help...even if you want to understand how the website works!!

Comment: Really thanks alot  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62613892/not-able-to-groupby-by-one-level-in-my-dataframe-by-pandas   .. you can find my question

Comment: @ManojKumar: I checked the answer given by Yoben_s in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612488/how-to-crate-the-group-by-in-pandas-only-in-one-level . It is working perfectly fine for me. Coming the same output as you need. Let me know the exact problem you are getting while implementing above solution

Comment: No Rahul is not working from Yoben because i am extracting from Excel but he created a dats   as list that i cant do while importing a excel file .. could you please show me how did u do that ..even Datanovice also did .. but if u see result Month is not in assending way ..

Comment: I also did from excel...in one sheet I wrote your data..then simply run the code from Yoben , I am getting the month in ascending way.

Comment: I can only think is..you have older version of pandas to check please run `import pandas as pd print(pd.__version__)`. Let me know what is the pandas version

Comment: Hey Buddy .. its 0.25.3

Comment: Hi...it is updated version only....Don't know why this is happening with you man!! I tried the exact same and is working fine!!

Comment: Well thanks a ton Rahul.. i am able to do so.... just asking another question ...I have 2 data Frame (df1 and df2) which are having diffrent headers and i want to add into one data Frame as df3 . so when ever df1 ends then after one row df 2 must be displayed.. is it possiable ?

Comment: Yes..by `df3 = pd.conact[df1,df2]`

Comment: Thanks Rahul for alwyes help and ssupport .. i already fixed this ... just asking is there any around where i can i use the function add  0 in last number of each cell